# chart.js is not drawing the line graph for the firestore dataset

Tags: javascript, firebase, chart.js

Actually, I have got data from the Firestore and trying to show up in the line graph using chart.js.

Graph labels and data are showing up correctly in the X and Y positions accordingly. But it is not drawing the line on the graph.

So far I did:

`.jsp` file -->

```
            <div>
                <canvas id="myChart"  style="padding-top: 40px; height: 6px; width: 36px" height="6" width="36"></canvas>   
            </div>
```

`.js` file -->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    var db = firebase.firestore();
        var docRef = db.collection('Users').doc('6158614499').collection('Data').orderBy("Date", "desc");
        var timeOptions = {hourCycle: 'h23', hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'};
    var dateOptions = { day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric' };


    var labelsDateArray = [];
    var dataValuesArray = [];


    docRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
        var one = doc.data();
        
        
        var date = one.Date.toDate().toLocaleDateString('en-CA', dateOptions) + "~" +  one.Date.toDate().toLocaleTimeString( [],  timeOptions);
        labelsDateArray.push(date);
        var value = one.FacilityCode;
        dataValuesArray.push(value);



        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labelsDateArray,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Kefa-Firestore-Dataset',
                fill: false,
                showLine: true,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba (75, 192, 192,0.4)",
                borderColor: "rgba(139, 0, 0, 1)",
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(139, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "red",
                pointBorderWidth: 2,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
                pointRadius: 3,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                        data: dataValuesArray,
            }]
        },
    
        });
    
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
    
});
```

Output is like this:

[image]

So, in order to draw the line what should I change, anyone can help please?!

Comment: Can you share a sample value of "dataValuesArray"? I think this is not in a right format

Comment: Omg, I have given another variable as an input. I have changed it and now it is working... thanks for your comment